# Use webhost dns directly bypassing domain

Tags: networking, dns, domain

This might be a stupid questions, since I don't know enough about how domains and the whole IP resolving infrastructure work but...

I have a domain, let's say `domain.com`. It's set up to point to my current website which I want operational for now. I have also aquired a new web-hosting solution (for creation of a New Better Website), and informed it that I will want to use my `domain.com` (as that's how I'll want it to work when I finish) as the address. Now however I seem to be unable to enter my new site to see how I'm doing - since it says I should access it through `domain.com`, and my domain is busy redirecting to the old site. My hosting solution doesn't provide any alternative link or direct access IP, it also doesn't seem to allow multiple domains.

Is there a way to hack my way through (even temporarily) and load the new website without changing domain settings (and therefore making my users loose access to the old site prematurily)? I tried using `nslookup mydomain.com ns1.dns.address`, but that didn't point to anywhere usefull...

Comment: can you connect by IP?

Comment: @FrankThomas That was how I attempted to resolve the problem myself - however  webhost admin panel does not provide the IP, and my attempt at obtaining it through nslookup failed (though I might have used it incorrectly).

Comment: If you don't have a (shared) IP address, how would you even point the domain to the new host?

Comment: Ok, correction - I do have some address (I can log in through FTP for example), but going there through http brings 404... Webhost configuration just said to input domain name and "delegate domain to their dns server".

Comment: You'll have to call it `new.domain.com` or something like that while you work on it, you won't be able to access it otherwise. And don't forget to add a `robots.txt` to prevent search engines indexing a not finished website. You could make your hosts file or local DNS server point to the new server, but you couldn't access the old one then.

Comment: @Deltharis To clarify: You need an IP address. They will use name-based virtual hosts, so browsing to the IP address directly won’t work. So again: Do you have this IP address? Perhaps your new hosting provider has a guide on how to use a third-party DNS service? It would have to contain information on where to get the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you understand how managing Domain names work.
1. You probably paid a provider (like godaddy) to purchase your Domain name.
From there you can use their DNS system or point to another one. Either way the DNS provider will have some sort of control panel where you can point your domain names to the IP of where your web site is hosted.
2. With 1 Domain name you can have multiple web sites on multiple hosts.
3. If you would like to test a new website you are building you would call it something like temp.mydomain.com and you would point temp.mydomain.com to the host ip address where your web site resides.
4. On the host side, normally you would also have some sort of control panel to create your Vitual Hosts where your websites reside. It is there that you would setup your site to listen for incoming requests from the DNS server.